# How to light multi-level lego building using LED in such a way that each level can be easily removed without using connectors

Tags: led

I have two questions here so please review both in the event you can help me with one or the other.

**First**.
We have lego buildings are that are multi-levels and each level can be easily separated. I'd like to add LED lights to each level so that when the levels are stacked, you can see inside of them but would like to be able to lift up each level without having to disconnect JST connectors (or something similar). I found this [website](https://www.lightmybricks.com/products/wireless-power-connector-2-pack-lego-lighting?_pos=1&_sid=ef71a70c0&_ss=r) but $15 is steep for something I can easily make myself if I knew what the parts were called. They have a video of it in action here: https://youtu.be/57hEFSk0uHA (safe for work viewing)

There are more pictures available at the vendor's website [HERE](https://www.lightmybricks.com/products/wireless-power-connector-2-pack-lego-lighting?_pos=1&_sid=ef71a70c0&_ss=r) but I'm including one here for quick reference. The lego with the copper foil would be at the top of level one  and the brick with the two studs would be at the bottom of the level two. Not viewable in my image but the vendor's images show it, the lego brick with the two studs has embedded in it what I assume is copper foil, would make a connection when stacked and then power would be continued to level two. When level two is lifted up, power would be cut. The video shows this in action and may be easier to follow than my text.

**Second**.
In the second picture below, I'd pointing out two items. The first item is how the "wireless power connected is installed" but I'd also like to bring your attention to the circuit board mounted to the wall where the JST plugs are connected. Can someone tell me what this is actually called so I can find it online? It's an expansion board but I need more information to narrow down search results, plesae.

I thought about using copper foil tape, Neodymium magnets, or silver solder precut chips around 5mm but I would like to know if there might be a better option. I need about 70 connections (70 + and 70 - connections) which is another reason why I want to make them rather than drop $1000 on a light kit ($15 x 70 = $1050).

**RECAP**.
Ultimately, I'm looking for a way to run power (12VDC) without using JST (or similar) connectors, preferably with metal contact points as illustrated in my images above that, and that wont break the bank. I'm asking for help with ideas and part names, please.

[image: product image 1]
[image: product image 2]

Comment: Those use spring leaf connectors or pogo pins, spring loaded connectors. Design and implementation is up to you.

Comment: @Passerby - something like this? https://amz.run/5igE ?

Comment: Probably. They come in a ton of dimensions, and you can get them in sets where multiple are connected with plastic, like a standard header but with pogopins instead of fixed header pins. You want one that fits in whatever block you want to use, or 3D print something.

Comment: @Passerby if you'll make your first comment an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thank you.